# Kotlin: How to create a higher order function that works inside suspend and non-suspend functions? (other than inline)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, higher-order-functions

So basically, I want to create a high order function like `run`, that works inside non-functions as it works in suspend functions.

What seems to make it work is the `inline` modifier, but I'm sure that comes with some sort of overhead, so I'm wondering if there's another way.

Comment: `inline` is typically *less* overload because it avoids creating a function wrapper class under the hood for the passed function.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `inline` is the only way to achieve this. It is also a commonly used solution, both in stdlib and 3rd party code.

Regarding the overhead: it is actually the opposite. Higher-order functions are better to be inlined anyway - because of the performance. Drawback is the increased size of the resulting bytecode, so slightly increased memory usage. However, this shouldn't be a concern as long as the inlined function isn't really big.